# facebox rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, facebox

how do I use facebox in a Rails app knowing that I already have the jquery-rails gem installed? Need sample code that goes into the view as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Include facebox library in your application.html.erb file.

Add this code in a javascript file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
})
```

View

```
<a href="images/stairs.jpg" rel="facebox">text</a>
```

There are a few simple examples and some documentation on their site https://github.com/defunkt/facebox#usage.