# Facebox not working with rails 3.2.13

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebox

I'm trying to make a form input inside a facebox but after install the gem facebox-rails and trying to run a sample [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879288/facebox-rails-app) but changed the link to a html page of mine. Simply facebox doesn't work, just open the page on my browser; When I started to dig what can make the things gone wrong, a caught this error with firebug:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'facebox'
```

Anyone can give me a light to fix this or what I'm doing wrong?